# Common practice for reibursement of business travel expenses done in foreign currency

Tags: business, travel, reimbursement

I am back from a business trip outside my home country, and I have done various expenses in foreign currency using my credit card. This includes conference tickets & accommodation which are far from being small amounts.

As we are a small company, we do not have proper processes, dedicated accountants, reporting software, corporate travel agents... in place yet. I book everything on my own then file expense reports once the trip is over.

The thing is: as I spend something in foreign currency on my credit card, I get the charge in my home currency with an arbitrary exchange rate applied by the credit card company.
The receipts that I am going to file for my reports obviously do not mention the converted amount. If the company selects a different exchange rate as a basis for reimbursement, there can be some profit or loss.

What is the commonly accepted practice for reimbursing expenses done in foreign currencies? Should I note the corresponding charges and pass them along with the receipts? Or should the company reimburse me using its "own" rate and let me bear the exchange rate "risk"?

Answer (score 1):

> arbitrary exchange rate applied by the credit card company

The exchange rates of credit cards are deterministic. You just need to input your bank's fee ranging from 0% to 3.5% into the tools. Your credit card statement or agreement should have explicitly stated the fee.

https://www.mastercard.us/en-us/personal/get-support/convert-currency.html

https://usa.visa.com/support/consumer/travel-support/exchange-rate-calculator.html

There are different common practices for expense reports:

1. Fill the expense report purely in home currency, attach receipts in foreign currency, then attach credit card statement showing the relationship between each home currency amount and foreign currency amount.
2. Fill the expense report in foreign currency. Let the system calculate home currency (at ridiculous rates). Create 1 new line for the difference between the total your company calculated (home currency) and the total on your credit card statement (home currency). Call it "Miscellaneous: Exchange Rate Difference". Attach the credit card statement.
3. Override the company suggested exchange rate for each line and attach the credit card statement and agreement, along with the Mastercard/Visa links. Overriding is supported in SAP, which is the most popular expense report tool.

Comment: Would you attach the entire CC statement that also includes personal expenses not related to the travel, or cut an excerpt of it? For privacy concerns

Comment: I redact it with Adobe Acrobat. You may also consider having a dedicated "business" card for business purpose.

Comment: #4 - get the company credit card and only submit receipts